# "Aw, Snap! Something went wrong while displaying this webpage."

Tags: google-chrome, windows-10, chromium

Using the Google Chrome browser on a regular basis has given me great service and usability. 2-3 weeks ago, for whatever reason it stopped working completely. Meaning, that when I start the application the regular Chrome window pops up but nothing is shown but the message **"Oh no!
there has been a problem showing the website."** Also: I can open and see the menu but when clicking on one item nothing happens... Not being able to access the settings etc.

I tried *all* of the tricks and tweaks as suggested in plenty of forums etc. With no positive outcome. Still not working. So I tried different browsers with the following results:

- Firefox: **working**
- Opera: **working**
- Microsoft Edge: **working**
- (new Chromium-based) Microsoft Edge Insider: **not working**
- (and of course) Google Chrome: **not working**

So I thought it had something to do with Chrome and the new Microsoft Edge Insider being based on Chromium. That the problem could potentially have something to do with this. But since Opera is also Chromium-based and running on my machine without a care I discarded that idea.

Has anyoney experienced behavior in Chrome like that? Or even has a solution how to get it back running?

btw I'm running Windows 10.

Comment: Does it work when you fire up Chrome in incognito mode? If it doesn't work in incognito mode either then try enabling logging in Chrome and checkout the log file to see, why it's behaving like that

Comment: @Asesh Thanks for the hint. Incognito mode also doesn't work.
I managed to get the logging in Chrome enabled and also checked out the log-file, but honestly from all that horky-borky (almost 7000 lines) text I didn't really understand anything. Any hints on what to look out for?

Comment: Look for `Error` string and go through those error messages

Answer (score 1):

To fix this issue in **Windows** OS follow the below steps

1. Open windows registry
2. Goto HKLM or HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
3. Goto to Software\Policies
4. Create "**Google**" Key
5. Under the Google, Create "**Chrome**"
6. Select **Chrome** and right-click and select **DWORD (32-bit)** Type
   **RendererCodeIntegrityEnabled** and set the value as **0**
7. Reopen the browser. It will start working

This worked for me

Comment: This is not the right solution for this issue. There could be so many reasons behind the issue.

Comment: I understand your point but this is a temporary measure till Google team fixes a compatibility issue with windows OS

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit difficult to diagnose just based on the report here, but you can try to follow the guide at https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines/reporting-crash-bug

I've generally only run into this when there are ABI issues, like missing or mismatched dlls, which cause repeated process crashes.